# C# Reading errors in log file using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have huge log file and in this i need to read and find all the errors and errors looks like in following format.

```
TX: 000001270
PROCESSING: 2015-666-001211-0000
CONVERSION FAILURE!
ERROR: the given number not find in  transaction table.
Removed TransactionSet

TX: 0000018887
PROCESSING: 2915-966-001888-0000
CONVERSION FAILURE!
ERROR: Object reference not set an instance of object.
Removed TransactionSet
```

Can anyone help me with regular expression to read all the errors into datatable/list with Processing number and Error Message. (or) please suggest is there any other better solution to read this.

Expected output format (as List or Data table)

```
Processing           |  ErrorMessage
-------------------- |  ----------------------------------------------
2015-666-001211-0000 |  the given number not find in  transaction table.
-------------------- |  ----------------------------------------------
2915-966-001888-0000    Object reference not set an instance of object.
-------------------- |  ----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Split on \r\n\r\n then loop looking for `\r\nERROR:` ?

Comment: What is the expected output for the given example?

Comment: If there is always a processing/error pair, you can use something simple `(?m)^PROCESSING:\h*(.*)(?<!\s)[\S\s]*?^ERROR:\h*(.*)(?<!\s)` that does trimming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this (*Linq*):

```
  String prefix = "ERROR: ";

  var result = File
   .ReadLines(@"C:\MyLog.txt")
   .Where(line => line.StartsWith(prefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   .Select(line => line.Substring(prefix.Length)); // <- let's remove "ERROR: " prefix

  // the given number not find in  transaction table. 
  // Object reference not set an instance of object.
  String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
```

**Edit**: unfortunatelly, standard *Linq* doesn't implement either `Lag()` or `Lead()` methods (however, *More Linq* https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/ has them), so the code will be combersome:

```
  String processing = "";

  var result = File
   .ReadLines(@"C:\MyLog.txt")
   .Where(line =>
     line.StartsWith("ERROR: ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
     line.StartsWith("PROCESSING: ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   .Select(line => { // Lag() emulation
      if (line.StartsWith("PROCESSING: ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        processing = line.Substring("PROCESSING: ".Length);
        return "";
      }
      else
        return processing + " | " + line.Substring("ERROR: ".Length);
      })
   .Where(line => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(line));

   //2015-666-001211-0000 | the given number not find in  transaction table.
   //2915-966-001888-0000 | Object reference not set an instance of object.
   String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry! The above code is giving error message only, i need Processing number and the error message for each transaction set TX. I updated the output format in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a dictionary (assuming the processing number is unique). Basically when it encounters a "PROCESSING: " line it'll add an entry to the dictionary with an empty string for the value, then the next time it encounters an "ERROR:" line it'll set the value of the previous inserted key. Tested with 1 million error records (so 7 million lines, 150MB filesize) took 4.7 seconds

```
Dictionary<string, string> Errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string lastProcessingNumber = string.Empty;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("log.txt"))
{
    while(!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        if(line.StartsWith("PROCESSING"))
        {
            lastProcessingNumber = line.Replace("PROCESSING: ", string.Empty);
            Errors.Add(lastProcessingNumber, string.Empty);
        }

        if(line.StartsWith("ERROR") && lastProcessingNumber != string.Empty)
        {
            Errors[lastProcessingNumber] = line.Replace("ERROR: ", string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is definitely a good and appropriate option for something like this.  As long as you know what you're doing with it, since it's a declarative language, it will likely be cleaner, simpler, and more flexible than any of the imperative alternatives.

There are many variations of regex patterns which will work, and it depends on your specific needs, but something along the lines of the following pattern should work for you:

```
PROCESSING: (?<processing>[^\r\n]*)(.|\r|\n)*?ERROR: (?<error>[^\r\n]*)
```

You could use it like this:

```
string pattern = @"PROCESSING: (?<processing>[^\r\n]*)(.|\r|\n)*?ERROR: (?<error>[^\r\n]*)";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
    {
        string processing = m.Groups["processing"].Value;
        string error = m.Groups["error"].Value;
        // Insert into database
    }
```